# I am missing something about .env, could you explain it to me?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, dotenv

I have a very, basic, need: to store different endpoints for my APIs according to the environment. Suppose a simple file like this:

```
API_URL=http://localhost:8080
```

it should become, for my prod environment:

```
API_URL=http://myprodServer
```

and I'd like to have an integration test and a uat endpoint too!

Looking at my package.json I see:

```
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
```

So my idea is:

1. Put a command line argument near to "build" and "start" so to specify local and production enviroment files
2. Have a way to access to said configuration in my app, say config.API_URL

Now, I come from spring boot, and in spring boot I have a file per environment.

I though dotenv could be my solution but I see two strange things on their website:

1. Please don't commit your .env file --> so, how are my colleagues supposed to build my application? I usually at least push local and test environment, while keeping the uat and production files directly under the server
2. You should have just one .env file --> ok this one destroys me: if I just have one file how am I supposed to handle several environments???

What am I missing here? Could you help me solve my problem? I'm new to npm so I'm a little confused...

Comment: environment variable can be accessed in nodejs through `process.env` like `process.env.API_URL` `dotenv` is a substitute (convenience) for where you can define your environment variable. you can have a `config.js` file where you read all environment variables and export the config

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are using CRA to develop your React app.  If so, your env variables should be `REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:8080`.  Notice the prefix.  If you are using CRA, you must use the prefix.  More about that [here](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables).  If you do this correctly, the variable should be available in your javascript by using `process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL`.

At work, we each have a copy of the .`env` files locally, since we don't check it in.  We have different `.env` files for each environment - e.g - `.env.production`, `.env.development`, `.env.stage`.  We then have a run and build script for each environment in our `package.json`.  Using [`env-cmd`](https://github.com/toddbluhm/env-cmd) package, our scripts might look like this:

```
{
...
...
 "start": "react-scripts start",
 "start:stage": "env-cmd .env.stage.local react-scripts start",
 "start:production": "env-cmd .env.production.local react-scripts start",
 "build": "react-scripts build",
 "build:stage": "env-cmd .env.stage.local react-scripts build",
 "build:development": "env-cmd .env.development.local react-scripts build",
...
...
}
```

Along with this, we also have a git branch per environment so that on `stage` branch we would run `npm run build:stage` and deploy to Stage environment. We would do the same for production.

After looking around for a multi-environment setup, this is what I settled on and it works ok. However, I'd be open to improving the process.

Comment: Finally a clear explaination! It works thanks, I was missing the prefix :) One question though: as you pointed out I used CRA, is dotenv dependency in package.json necessary? Or I do have that already installed thanks to CRA?

Comment: Whether it is used under the hood in CRA or not, I'm not sure.  But you are right in that you don't need that dependency here as CRA handles it for you.  If you weren't using CRA as boilerplate, then you would use `dotenv` to get the job done.

Comment: Also, if in your travels you come across a better way of doing this or can think of things that might be better done differently, please reach out. I'd be interested to know.

Comment: Great answer. One thing I'll add is that it is somewhat common to provide a .env.example file as a template for creating the other .env files.